# Does celery worker run differently?

Tags: python, celery

I have a block of code which runs fine in my python application. When the celery worker runs this code, it fails to do so. Here is the code block:

```
def send_case_complete_email(owner_name, case_name, email):
    try:
        with open("utility/email/buildCompleteEmail.txt", 'rb') as email_file:
            text = email_file.read().decode("utf-8")
        text = text.replace("<owner>", owner_name).replace("<caseName>", case_name)
        msg = MIMEText(text)
        msg['Subject'] = "Case \'" + case_name + "\' is ready"
        msg['From'] = config_access.app_configs['email']['from']
        msg['To'] = email
        server = smtplib.SMTP(config_access.app_configs['email']['host'])
        if config_access.app_configs['email']['tls']:
            server.starttls()
        server.login(config_access.app_configs['email']['user'], config_access.app_configs['email']['password'])
        server.sendmail(config_access.app_configs['email']['from'], email, msg.as_string())
        print("Case completion email sent to " + email)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

With the error from the celery worker:

```
[2017-06-02 15:07:19,031: WARNING/PoolWorker-1] (500, b"5.3.3 Unrecognized command 'bm8ucmVwbHlAcGx1cmlsb2NrLmNvbQ==' [BN3PR03CA0080.namprd03.prod.outlook.com]")
```

Why would this happen?

Comment: Why are you using a try-catch block here? If you don't catch the exception you would get a full traceback, instead of just a single cryptic error message.

Comment: The celery worker typically run as some other user. `sys.path` could be different than what's expected. Looks like the celery worker maybe doesn't have access to the SMTP service you are using to send emails.

Comment: "run as some other user" how can find out this information?

Comment: If you are using linux, you can use a program such as `ps` to see which user a process is running under.

Answer (score 0):

The message you have posted is just a warning message. Are you sure the error here is from this piece of code. You can use logging here. [Python Logging](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html.)

Or if you are using Django then,[Django Logging](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/logging/)
. You can use `logger.exception` to get the full stacktrace. This shall tell you where exactly is the error coming from.